# Reliably identifying a Teams guest user

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft Teams tab app and I'm using SSO for authentication. My users are both native and guests. My requirement is to show different screens depending on the type of incoming user (native/guest), so I have to identify the user type first. To ensure security, I first obtain the id token for the incoming user and then validate it first before identifying the user type. Is there any reliable way to identify the incoming user type with just the id token? I don't trust the info in tab context.

Comment: Hi Perumal, could you please [decode](https://jwt.io/) your id token and share a sample(or screenshot) of it, I want to see if there is any fields in it which may help this problem (please cover the sensitive information of your id token).

Comment: Hi Perumal, may I know if this problem was solved ? I just want to know if your id token contains the objectId or username(email) of the user ?

Comment: Thanks @HuryShen for keeping track on this. I could always check the username/email address but I don't think it's a reliable way to identify the guest as it could be from multiple domains. What I'm looking for is some kind of an AAD attribute which identifies the incoming user as a guest as guest users in AAD are created indeed as "Guest Users"

Comment: Hi Perumal, I don't think we can distinguish the user directly just by id token. What I want to provide is a solution call a api with the parameter(email or objectId) from the id token and there is a attribute(aad attribute) in its response which can help us distinguish if the user is guest or not. Do you accept this kind way ?

Comment: And if you accept this way, please [decode](https://jwt.io/) your id token and confirm if it contains "objectId" of the user because use "objectId" is better than use "email".

Comment: @HuryShen What api are you talking about here that will provide me with that attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Microsoft Graph API, you could add all the guest user into a security Group and include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the ID token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["1ce9c55a-9826-4e32-871c-a8488144bb32"]
}
```

You can also [Add app roles in your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. This solution works however our guest user base is dynamic. Though it's regulated through a registration process, there could be thousands of guests at any point in time joining and leaving our app. Adding them all to a group for one time is fine, but every time when there are new guests will be a significant operational overhead for our admins. Let me think over this.

Comment: @PerumalPerumal You can create a dynamic group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-create-rule#to-create-a-group-membership-rule. Add a rule to add guest into this group dynamically. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxqyv.png.

Comment: Thanks again. While I think over the dynamic groups in AAD feature you suggested, for now, I use the logic of depending on the existence of the "upn" field of the id_token. It seems like guests don't have this field, but only internal users do

Comment: @PerumalPerumalp May I know why you need to use `upn`? Could you please describe your scene so that I can tell if there is a workaround.

Comment: I actually don't have any compulsions to use "upn" attribute. All I'm trying to do is trying to uniquely identify the incoming user as a guest from the acquired id_token. When I examined the JWT id_token, I found that the "upn" attribute is present only in internal users and not in guest users. This is why I decided to use it. If there is a better way to handle this, I'm more than willing to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use microsoft graph api(beta) [get user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

If the id token contains objectId of the user, just put the objectId as the parameter of this api. In the response, we can find an attribute `userType`. The value of this attribute could be `Member` or `Guest`.

If the id token doesn't contain objectId of the user, just contains email. We can also put it as the parameter in the graph api, but if the email is a guest user, the api will not get response data. So I asked you if it contains objectId in the comments.

By the way, the attribute `userType` just exists in the beta version of microsoft graph api but not exist in the v1.0 version microsoft graph api. So if you're not comfortable with beta version, I suggest to use Azure AD graph api([get user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#basic-operations-on-users--)) instead of Microsoft graph api.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution does not work for me as per our security guidelines, we are not allowed to invoke graph api as a guest user.

Comment: Hi @PerumalPerumal According to my understanding, you don't want guest user to invoke graph api. But when it complete the SSO and get the id token with objectId or email, you can use a native user(authenticate the access token) to invoke the graph api(with the parameters "objectId" or "email" from id token) in your code. If I misunderstand your requirements, please let me know.

Comment: The way our app works, the approach you suggested may not be possible. In my code I have a landing page which is common for both guests and internal users. I validate the incoming user with an id token and then branch out to different views based on the type of the incoming user. It is here that I identify the user type using some adhoc methods and then route them to different page views. Now, when a guest user tries to login, the user context will of the guest. How do I invoke the graph api in the context of an internal user in this scenario?